# Grab a website with PHP and then traverse it with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, parsing

I'm building a system where I'll need to grab the contents of a web page with PHP and then parse it to extract certain tables etc. Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery or would the best way be to write PHP function to extract the data?

Comment: This may help, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery has nothing to do with PHP and can't be run without a browser, so you're out of luck there.

However, there is [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) that allows DOM parsing with jQuery's selectors!

Comment: Actually jQuery can be run without a browser (Rhino, V8, etc)... but that's beside the point. It's just a small addendum.

Answer (score 4):

Do It like this in php with native php [DOM functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and xpath:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $x = new DOMXPath($dom);
    // grab all tables with id of foo
    foreach($x->query("//table[@id='foo']") as $node)
    {
        // here is the html
                    echo $node->c14n();
                    // grab the containing text 
                    echo $node->textContent()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM functions available in PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't. jQuery is for JavaScript, which is client-side, and requires a JavaScript engine to execute.

I would suggest you read the HTML as XML, but you'll run into all sorts of trouble if the HTML is not XHTML valid.

Answer (score 0):

this is awesome

http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

example:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: Don't do this. I used to use simplehtmldom all the time, but it is slow as molasses. Use the built in dom functions. They are an order of magnitude faster. Here is a benchmark to prove it: http://whitlock.ath.cx/FastCrawl/benchmark.php

Comment: can agree but i had some issues with DOM not want to parse sometimes due encoding problem (anyways the file was UTF-8).. at least on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

There are a few php packages that can help you with this, curl, dom and xpath.

Here's [a good tutorial](http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/php/scraping-links-with-php/) I've used before.